# remove array keys that has not one value at least

Tags: php, arrays

i have multidimensional array..in this array i have many arrays..i want to filter their keys..to do that i want to remove the keys that has not any value in all arrays..so how to do this in the right way

```
        $cell_values = array_map('array_filter', $values);
print_r($cell_values);
```

this will filter them all but i want to let the key if it have any value in another array..

arrays like thts

```
    Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1010
                [B] => -6989548.4
                [C] => 
                [D] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1020
                [B] => 20554
                [C] => 28.8
                [D] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1030
                [B] => 15151
                [C] => 
                [D] => 
            )

the expected output like this

    Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1010
                [B] => -6989548.4
                [C] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1020
                [B] => 20554
                [C] => 28.8

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [A] => 1030
                [B] => 15151
                 [C] => 28.8

            )
```

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: show it above.. i modified it

Comment: Use array_filter function

Comment: array_walk() with an array_filter() callback?

Comment: What? Where is the logic ? Why do you keep C in the first array?

Comment: because i want to keep keys that has one value at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First figure out which keys have at least 1 value. Then loop through the array and unset any keys that do not have at least 1 value.

```
$keys_with_values = array();

foreach($arrays as $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value) {
            $keys_with_values[$key] = 1;
        }
    }
}

foreach($arrays as &$array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($keys_with_values[$key]))
            unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1080247 that's what this does. did you try it?

Comment: Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 1
    [C] => 1
    [D] => 1
    [E] => 1
    [F] => 1
    [G] => 1
    [H] => 1
    [I] => 1
    [J] => 1
    [K] => 1
    [L] => 1
    [M] => 1
    [N] => 1
    [O] => 1
    [P] => 1
)

Comment: @user1080247 you're outputting `$keys_with_values` instead of `$arrays`